# .Net AWS DynamoDB Updating items

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb object persistence model with .net core c#.

I am using the following to save my data:

```
public Task SaveAsync(T item)
{
   return base.SaveAsync(item, _config);
}
```

While this works fine. I wanted to know how can I update items instead of saving.
What I have is that I need to delete the item, and then call save again. Is it possible to overwrite the item instead of deleting and resaving.

For ex I have an item with key as my guid , when I call save I have to first delete this item and then insert another entry with a different guid.

Any update which is available with dynamo db?

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

How are you retrieving the item? are you getting it via the dbcontext? or dbClient?

When using the [Object Persistance model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CRUDHighLevelExample1.html), you should just save the item. the framework will take care of the update in the background. My assumption/guess is that you are loading the data outside of the dbcontext. So when you go to save it, it assumes you want to create a new item.

Comment: To add to what Neil said, when your item (of type T) is serialized to json by the .NET DynamoDB SDK, if the primary key (which is the partition key plus the sort key, if you have one on your table) is the same as an existing item, the existing item in the table will be overwritten. If the key is not a match for an existing item, it will be saved as a new item. Note that by default, writes to DynamoDB use eventual consistency model, so if you read it immediately after updating an item, it's possible you would get the "old" version.